# face recognition by opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

i have a code for face recognition by open cv python

```
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from time import sleep


def get_encoded_faces():
    """
    looks through the faces folder and encodes all
    the faces

    :return: dict of (name, image encoded)
    """
    encoded = {}

    for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk("./faces"):
        for f in fnames:
            if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".png"):
                face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + f)
                encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
                encoded[f.split(".")[0]] = encoding

    return encoded


def unknown_image_encoded(img):
    """
    encode a face given the file name
    """
    face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + img)
    encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]

    return encoding


def classify_face(im):
    """
    will find all of the faces in a given image and label
    them if it knows what they are

    :param im: str of file path
    :return: list of face names
    """
    faces = get_encoded_faces()
    faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
    known_face_names = list(faces.keys())

    img = cv2.imread(im, 1)
    #img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
    #img = img[:,:,::-1]

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
    unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations)

    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in unknown_face_encodings:
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        name = "Unknown"

        # use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        face_names.append(name)

        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, bottom -15), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(img, name, (left -20, bottom + 15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)


    # Display the resulting image
    while True:

        cv2.imshow('Video', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            return face_names 


print(classify_face("test-image");
```

it is taking image that we save to test but i want it to take image from camera then recognize it So any one here can please tell how i can change test image so it will take test image from camera not what we save in data base to test ...........

Comment: edit question and use special button `{}` to format code.

Comment: in every tutorial for opencv you should see how to get image from camera. `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and in loop `status, frame = cap.read()`

Comment: Yeah i see many codes but when i put that code that are taking images from camera into my existing code it do not works

Comment: if you get any tutorial for opencv you will see how to use it - and you would create solution 2 days ago :) Next time first use Google to find solution - you may get solution much faster then asking on Stackoverflow.

Comment: BTW: if you want to test single frame from camera then simply use it instead of `img = cv2.imread(im, 1)` - like `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `status, img = cap.read()`. If you want to check all frames in stream then you may need more changes - you will need loop which will read frame - like in tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check single frame from camera then simply use

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
status, img = cap.read()
```

instead of

```
img = cv2.imread(im, 1)
```

---

If you want to check faces in stream then you need to put all in loop

```
def classify_face(im):

    faces = get_encoded_faces()
    faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
    known_face_names = list(faces.keys())

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:

        status, img = cap.read()

        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
        unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in unknown_face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

            for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
                # Draw a box around the face
                cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)

                # Draw a label with a name below the face
                cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, bottom -15), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                cv2.putText(img, name, (left -20, bottom + 15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Video', img)

        print(face_names)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            return
```

---

**EDIT:** Full code (with small changes) for work with video stream. It works for me. But if previous function did works for you then this version may not help you - function `classify_face` is almost the same as in previous example.

```
import os
import cv2
import face_recognition as fr
import numpy as np


def get_encoded_faces(folder="./faces"):
    """
    looks through the faces folder and encodes all
    the faces

    :return: dict of (name, image encoded)
    """
    encoded = {}

    for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(folder):
        for f in fnames:
            if f.lower().endswith(".jpg") or f.lower().endswith(".png"):

                fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                face = fr.load_image_file(fullpath)

                # normally face_encodings check if face is on image - and it can get empty result
                height, width = face.shape[:2]
                encoding = fr.face_encodings(face, known_face_locations=[(0, width, height, 0)])
                if len(encoding) > 0:
                    encoding = encoding[0]
                    encoded[f.split(".")[0]] = encoding

    return encoded


def classify_face(im):
    """
    will find all of the faces in a given image and label
    them if it knows what they are

    :param im: str of file path
    :return: list of face names
    """
    faces = get_encoded_faces()
    faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
    known_face_names = list(faces.keys())

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:

        status, img = cap.read()
        #print('status:', status)

        face_locations = fr.face_locations(img)
        unknown_face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(img, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for location, face_encoding in zip(face_locations, unknown_face_encodings): # I moved `zip()` in this place

            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = fr.compare_faces(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = fr.face_distance(faces_encoded, face_encoding)

            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

            top, right, bottom, left = location
            # Draw a box around the face

            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, bottom -15), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(img, name, (left -20, bottom + 15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)

        print('face_names:', face_names)
        cv2.imshow('Video', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            return face_names 

# --- main ---

print(classify_face("test-image"))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thanks alot sir, it works perfectly for image and when i try for a loop with continuous video stream from camera it runs  with out any error  but it  do not open came and take recording ??????? can you tell me whats problem sir

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. Inside loop you need `imshow()` and also `waitKey()` which updates image in window.

Comment: { while True:

        imshow()
        waitKey()

        status, img = cap.read() } in while true loop i put both you mention. and i put print() at end like this {   cv2.imshow('Video', img)

        print(face_names)
        print()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            return } rest of whole code is same but SIr, it is not giving output, Like after i run code it go to output window start blinking there with out results....... :(

Comment: {>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\ShanAli\Desktop\mechatronic project\face detection database\face_rec\face_rec.py 
>>> } its exit loop like this with out any error and with out opening cam

Comment: use more `print()` - ie. before every line print what command will do (like `print("run external for-loop")`, `print("I am inside for-loop")`. OR learn how to use debuger. If you have wrong values or wrong indentationt then it may run `return` and exit loop. See my code. And if you will still problem then create new question on new page - you will have more place to put full code and description. BTW: did you run code directly in terminal/console - `python script.py` - to see error messages ? If you run in some editor then it may close window with error before you can see it.

Comment: sir i upload complete code and i mentioned you there, can you please check ?

Comment: I see only old code in question - nothing new. And my old code from answer works with this old code. I don't know what you want. Why don't use `print()` to see which line is executed and what you have in variables. it will show you if it run code in correct order. Maybe you have wrong indentation and some code is never executed and it nevere run some function. But to see this you have to use `print()` in different places. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: sir, i wants my camera will continue be on and recognize faces, not like just take one picture and recognize it, your first comment work perfectly with image from camera but for loop video its not opening camera and donot giving any error thats why i am stuck like what to change to made it working. Its my project  and deadline is very close, i took alot of your time i am really sorry sir. i uses print() at many place as you mentioned bit no progress.

Comment: using `print()` you can recognize which line can make problems - it is line after `print()` which is displayed and before `print()` which is not displayed. And then you can try to find more information about code in this line. OR you will have to learn debuger to run code line by line and find line which makes problem. Using `print()` is only first step to recognize problem - to find line which makes problem.

Comment: using `print()` you can also see if it run lines in correct order and if it gets correct values in variables. If variable has wrong values then it may run `else` instead of `if` or it may skip `for`-loop instead of run `for`-loop. But usually it is problem because function works in different way then we expected. for example I found that `face_encodings` can return empty result because it may check if there is really face on image.

Comment: last idea - do you run it normally in terminla/console/cmd.exe/powershell `python script.py` ? Or you run it in some IDE (which could hide error message) ?

Comment: I add full code which works for me - but if previous version doesn't work for you then this version may not help you.

Comment: Furas sir second code is working perfectly with continuous video, but when i store my image in a database, it shows my name bill gates bcz bilgates image is also in data base its not recognizing clearly, but i goet idea thank you soo much for your help, Thanks alot your are real hero, thanks alot sir just last suggestion from you if i wants to turns on alarm for unknown person what should i edit in code ? Just last question sir, I know you will be busy, when ever you get time just teach me as you did, many time, thanks again sir

Comment: you would have to check `if "Unknown" in face_names: ...` after `for`-loop - this way you check it only once for frame - even if there are many unknow persons on frame. You would have to keep this information and compare with result for next frame - to not alarm if next frame has still "Unknown" persons. You can use module like [py-notifier](https://pypi.org/project/py-notifier/) to display popup window with messages/alarm.

Comment: I also send information (about motion in my garden) to [MQTT server](https://mosquitto.org/) (on Raspberry Pi) and 3 different computers at home can get it using Python module [paho-mqtt](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/) and display popup message.

Comment: { from pynotifier import Notification


Notification(
 title='Notification Title',
 description='Notification Description',
 icon_path='path/to/image/file/icon.png', 
 duration=5,                             
 urgency=Notification.URGENCY_CRITICAL
).send() **     Sir i install py notifier it installed succesfully now kindly you can tell me where in code i have to put this so its show pop up alarm  for unknown person. In first code where we are taking just one picture. Thank you so much for you help its means alot Sir, when ever you will be free please guide me Sir i will wait.

Comment: sir ....... i think i didnt mention you in this comment so you didnt see my comment above...

Comment: `import` should be at the beginning - to make code readable. Rest of code use when you get information about unknow person. You can use it when you display image or later.

Comment: sir, i put import at beginning and rest of code after unknown but its giving indent error again and again, I search alot how to use pynotifier but didnt found any thing.... can you please edit first code with pynotifier... so its make pop up type alarm for unknown person....this is last sir, i will not disturb again

Comment: indentantions means spaces and tabs - it is not problem with `pynotifier`. If you make wrong indentantions then Python doesn't know if code is inside `for/while/if/else/def/class` or outside. So check if you have the same indentations as in other lines.